# OpenAi-gymnasium: Huge memory usage even before gym.make()

Tags: python, openai-gym, memory-profiling

When I build a custom `gymnasium` (formerly gym) environment, and I see in the memory profile the first line, I get some headache.

Where does this huge memory footprint come from? For reference, when I create gymnasium environments like "Taxi-v3", I have only ~35 MiB ...

My general questions for this thread:

1. How is this first line measured?
2. Which influencing factors are taken to determine the outlined 82 MiB fdor the line @profile?

Console Output:

> Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
>
> =============================================================
>
> ```
> 9     82.1 MiB     82.1 MiB           1   @profile
> ```
>
> 10     82.1 MiB     0 MiB              1   def
> complete_walkthrough():
>
> 11
>
> 12     87.5 MiB      5.4 MiB           1        gym_env = gymnasium.make("MyEnv-v0")
> 13     88.4 MiB      0.9 MiB           1
> initial_state, _ = gym_env.reset()